# Are questioins about SSTP (VPN) off topic

Tags: discussion, off-topic

SSTP is a VPN variant that enables PPP traffic on top of SSL/TLS. As it works on top of SSL/TLS it can be considered above OSI layer 4.

Are the questions about operation of SSTP VPN off topic on this site?

Comment: It is something that you are configuring on your host/server. If it is for a business network (same requirement for Network Engineering), you could ask about it on [sf], but search there first because there are already questions and answers about it.